# Feeds: Error Importing Node Reference

Tags: 7, feeds, migrations

I am trying to import a node reference in my users's profile using feed and feeds profile modules and using a CSV file like this:

```
"Name","Email","Team"
"Pepe","Pepe@example.com","Team A"
"Juan","Juan@example.com","Team B"
"Pedro","Pedro@example.com","Team C"
```

My mapping configuration is like this:

```
SOURCE         | TARGET                                        | TARGET CONFIGURATION
Name             User name (name)                                Used as unique
Email            Mail                                            Used as unique
Team             team nid nid (profile2:main:field_team_nid_nid)
```

Team is a node reference to a content type that I had created.
When I try the import y receive this error message:

```
Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format.
```

Comment: I think the feed is expecting a node id for Team while you are delivering a textual value "Team A", etc. Is "Team A" the node title of the referenced node and have you already created these nodes?

Comment: Thank for your help. Yes it is. I created a content type named "Team" and I made 3 nodes of Team named "Team A" , "Team B" and "Team C". I need that my users are related with a node Team (e.g. "Pepe" who is from "Team A"). If I make a new user account manually I can choose his Team without problem, but I need to import a lot of users which I have in a CSV file.

Comment: You should try with the node id of the Team nodes instead of the node title in the import. This should work. If it is not feasible to change the import you could maybe go with https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper to change while importing.

Comment: `I need that my users are related with a node Team (e.g. "Pepe" who is from "Team A")` are you using Entity Reference of bundle User for this?

Comment: Stefan Korn I can´t do it with node id because I only have the node title in my CSV file.

Comment: No Sssweat no I don´t use it. I use a node reference that I can edit when I make a new user (I use profile2 module for this). Do you think that I should use Entity Reference?

Comment: Stefan I changed node title by nid in my CSV file and it works!! I thought that I can´t do it but later I thought search nid in the database. Thank you a lot and thank No Sssweat too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feed was expecting a node id and I was delivering a text value. I replaced the text value for node id corresponding in the CSV file and it works. I had to looking for node id value using phpmyadmin.